# Handle simple requests asynchronously through Django REST or by another method?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Firstly, sorry if the question is so obviously (I'm quite newbie). I have a Django project where the user can add or remove, for example, interests to his/her profile (ManyToMany relationship). I've achieve this with 3 views. The first one where the profile's interests are rendered, the second one to add (nothing is rendered, when the user click a link, the view just update the profile and return the first view, the one with the profile's interests) and the third one to remove interest.

**urls.py**

```
 path('home/overview/add/<int:interest_pk>', add_view, name="add_view"),
```

views.py

```
def add_view(request,interest_pk): #the third (the one to remove) view is similar 
    user = request.user
    user.profile.interests.add(Category.objects.filter(pk= category_pk).get())
    return redirect('overview') #Overview is the view where the interests are rendered
```

This works but now I'd like to improve this making it asynchronously. So here is my question, should I use Django Rest Framework to handle this kind of request (the ones related to the POST and DELETE methods) or is there any other method?

Note: I'm not using forms to send the information (I'd rather not to use it because it's simpler to send in an url the pk of the interest and handle it in a view) and I think it could be achieved  using only requests. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Which part of the code do you want to make asynchronous? Add more details about what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Ken4scholars I’d like to handle the requests for update the model asynchronously. So the user click on the link to add/remove interests, update his profile and display it again without reloading.

Comment: You're probably looking for ajax. It's more of a frontend question and not django rest framework

Comment: @Ken4scholars can I modify models using Ajax without forms?

Comment: First, you have to decide what you want to use. Django forms or just Django REST API with a dedicated JS frontend. Then read up on Ajax and how it is used. If you do have a specific question after that, you can post here